# Distance from affine vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, affine-geometry

I've got an affine vector space $W$ defined by a collection of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$. Each vector in that space could be represented as a sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i * v_i$, where $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$

Now to the question which is really simple.
If I have a vector $u \in W$ and wish to find $\{w_1, w_2, ... w_n\}$, I simply dot product $u$ by $\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$, correct?

Now, if we have a vector $s \notin W$ and wish to find it's distance from $W$, do we simply:

1. subtract $v_1$ from $s$ and $\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$
2. Do the dot product with {$\{v_2, ... v_n\}$}
3. Sum up the resulting $s' = \sum_{i=2}^n w_i * v_i$
4. Subtract and compute the norm (length) of $s - s'$

or is there a simpler way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Simply taking dot products with the spanning vectors will not in general work.

Your algorithm for distance finding would work...but only if the spanning vectors $v_i$ were pairwise orthogonal and all unit length.

Summary: if you first apply Gram-Schmidt to the spanning vectors, then there's actually some hope of this whole process working.

To see that dot products alone don't work, suppose that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are unit vectors but $v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0.5$. Then if you apply your first idea to the vector $u = v_1$, you'll find that 
$$
w_1 = u \cdot v_1 = v_1 \cdot v_1 = 1\\
w_2 = u \cdot v_2 = v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0.5
$$
and you'd be claiming that 
$$
v_1 = u = 1 v_1 + 0.5 v_2
$$
which is evidently wrong.

Comment: I need to Gram-Schmidt but I can't at first cause it's an affine subspace, I would probably need to subtract one of the vectors first (from the rest) and then GS the base vectors.

Comment: Yes. In fact, for most questions about affine spaces, I prefer to think of a "frame" -- a point $P$ and a set of vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_k$. To get such a frame from your $v_i$s, you take any affine combination of the $v_i$s to be $P$, and $u_i = v_i - P$ for, say, all but the last $i$. So an affine plane, described by $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$ becomes, say $[P = v_1, u_1 = v_2 - v_1, u_2 = v_3 - v_1]$. The inverse operation is pretty simple as well. Anyhow, you need to GS the $u_i$s, not the $v_i$s. Sorry for being glib.